# fscanf only reads one line

Tags: c, file, file-handling

This may have some other mistakes. But the only thing I concern is fscanf. It doesn't read new line. It reads only the first line. Can you please tell me how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void){

    int no = 0;
    FILE *cPtr;

    cPtr = fopen("number.dat","a");
    if(cPtr==NULL){
        printf("Unexpected error detected while creating new file\n");
    }

    do{

    printf("Enter your number : ");
        scanf("%d",&no);
        if(!(no==-99)){
            fprintf(cPtr,"%d\n",no);
        }

    }while(!(no==-99));

    fclose(cPtr);

    int n,i;
    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("number.dat","r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=1;i<10;i++){

        fscanf(fp,"%d",&n);
        printf("\n%d",n);

        fclose(fp);

    }


}
```

Comment: `
        fclose(fp);

    }
` you close the file.

Comment: simply move `fclose` out of the loop

Comment: Furthermore I'm afraid that if the file contains several lines `fscanf(fp,"%d",&n);` will not _consume_ the `'\n'`s. Try using `fscanf(fp," %d",&n);`.